# Counting the number of lines that special characters appear in a txt file from user input (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, raw-input

Using Python 2.7, I am trying to create a program that simulates the grep search command in Unix. In other words, I want to ask the user to enter a regular expression and then subsequently count the number of lines where the user's inputted regular expression appears in the file.

This is my code which I already know is totally messed up (I've been at this problem for hours now, and I am at my wit's end). In this code, I entered the string "^Author" which returned 0 lines when it should have returned approximately 1798 lines from the file that I have decided to open (the "what.txt" file):

```
import re
hand = open('what.txt')
yo = raw_input("Enter a regular expression: ")
count = 0
for line in hand:
    x = re.findall('.*[a-zA-Z]+.*', line)
    if yo in line and len(x) > 0:
        count += 1

print "what.txt had", count, "lines that matched %s" % yo
```

I am drawing a blank and haven't been able to find answers relating to this problem on StackOverflow. In short, any help would be awesome.

Comment: As a side note: You should get into the habit of using sensible names in your code, even if you're just fiddling around. `infile` and `pattern` really don't take more time to type than `hand` and `yo`, but make your code so much more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually using your regex in your search at the moment.

```
x = re.findall(yo, line)
if x:
    count += 1 # multiple non-overlapping occurences on one line

print "what.txt had {0} lines that matched {1}".format(count, yo)
```

Comment: All of you have swiftly solved my problem, and I am officially embarrassed that it took so little time to resolve this issue.

Itzmeontv - I can't believe that you can just type "if x" as a conditional statement and it will return a count! That's incredible.

Hobenkr - You are most definitely correct, I needed to pass in the raw_input in order to make it work. I think I was overcomplicating the issue. To be fair, I didn't know that you could pass in a raw_input like that, using regular expressions.

Forcebru- Your sample is the most beautiful demonstration of regex I have seen yet! Many thanks

Comment: Learning takes time. Python is powerful and with experience you can exploit some of these cool little iterable features. Good luck with your learning!

Comment: Thanks Matt! I really love StackOverflow and the community here. I would be totally lost without this kind of support. I'm thanking the high heavens right now for all of you helping me to get out of this rut that I was in. This problem was really stressing me out.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `re` module to handle the regex?

```
for line in hand.readlines():
    if re.findall(yo,line):
        count+=1
```

In your code you're using a regex as if it was just a string, but you have to use a module that works with regexes, such as `re`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you should be passing the expression you gather into `yo` to `re.findall()`. I'm not that familiar with grep, but just passing that to findall seems to work for me.

```
import re
hand = open('what.txt')
yo = raw_input("Enter a regular expression: ")
count = 0
for line in hand:
    x = re.findall(yo, line)
    if len(x) > 0:
        count += 1
        print(x)

print "what.txt had", count, "lines that matched %s" % yo
```